# Plotting a graph on maxima

Tags: maxima

I have been trying very hard to plot graph using maxima. Sadly it is not working. I tried uninstalling and installing multiple times. This is the error I am getting pictures below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YvCF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jwr9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I have provided code above.

Comment: Sorry to hear it's not working for you. (1) What does `wxbuild_info();` report? Please copy the output and paste it into the problem statement. (2) One possible problem is that the function `implicit_plot` is undefined for some reason, and that's why the image PNG doesn't exist. What happens if you say `load("implicit_plot");` and then the same `wximplicit_plot(...)` you tried before? What happens if you try `load("implicit_plot");` and then `implicit_plot(...)` ? (i.e. `implicit_plot` and not `wximplicit_plot`.)